# Android - TranslateAnimation from middle to top

Tags: android, animation

I want to animate an ImageView which starts at the center of the screen, and move it up 10 px below the top of the screen. How can I achieve this in code?

What I'm currently doing, is that I'm getting the screen coords upon another image, and place this animation image a bit on top of that, but in large screens with high density, it don't keep the same distance, so instead I want to move it 10px from the top.

How can I achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
//calculate where to put the logo in y-axis depending on screen size
            int coords[] = {0,0};
            logoImageFixed.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
            int y = coords[1];
            int imgFixedHeight = logoImageFixed.getHeight();
            Log.d("daim","height: "+imgFixedHeight);
            float pointY = -(y + 3*imgFixedHeight);

            Animation a = new LogoAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, pointY);
            a.setFillAfter(true);
            a.setDuration(600);
            a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    logoAnimated = true;
                }
            });
            logoImage.startAnimation(a);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well i think you're in the right path

```
int[] coords = {0,0};
logoImage.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
int y = coords[1];

//to top of screen  
TranslateAnimation toTop = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -y);
toTop.setDuration(700);
toTop.setFillAfter(true);
logoImage.startAnimation(toTop);
```

but if you want add padding 10 more pixel you need to do this

```
//padding 10 pixels from top    
TranslateAnimation toTop = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, ((-y) - 10));
toTop.setDuration(700);
toTop.setFillAfter(true);
logoImage.startAnimation(toTop);
```